# How to display API data by entering a postcode into a search bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, searchbar

I currently have an input search bar with a submit button and code that will display the API data that I want. However, in the URL for the API, it sets the location to the postcode "FK1 5LD" as you can see the section "area=FK1%205LD". The way the data is displayed and formatted works perfectly for me. But I would like to be able to type in the postcode "FK1 5LD" into the input search bar and when I click the submit button, it would display the API data I have already coded.

Thank you!

Search Bar and Button HTML

`<input name="search" placeholder="Search.." type="text"><button>Search</button>`

Javascript to display API information

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
   $(function() {
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/census/jobs_breakdown?area=FK1%205LD",
       method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var str = "";          
           for(var i= 0; i < data.jobsBreakdown.length; i++){

             str +='Job Title : '+data.jobsBreakdown[i].description+' <br> Total Number of People Engaged in Occupency : '+data.jobsBreakdown[i].value+' <br> Percentage of Occupancies in Area : '+data.jobsBreakdown[i].percentage.toPrecision(2)+'% <br><br>';
           }
          $("body").html(str);
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What you're looking to do is called "attaching an event handler". Basically, you are taking the API call you have already and linking it to something on the page (in this instance, the form field and button). @Kyle 's answer seems correct for what it sounds like you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might have missed the mark - but you just want to have the data call out for whatever is currently typed into the search field right?  If so this should do it - just need to make a few element references and expose the end of the url for updates.

```
<input id="mySearchField" name="search" placeholder="Search.." type="text">

<button id="mySearchButton">Search</button>
<div id="myContentArea></div>


<script>

       $(function() {
        var _myContentArea = document.getElementById("myContentArea");
        var _mySearchButton = document.getElementById("mySearchButton");
        _mySearchButton.onclick = getData;

        function getData(){
        var _mySearchField = document.getElementById("mySearchField");
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/census/jobs_breakdown?area="+_mySearchField.value,
           method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                var str = "";          
               for(var i= 0; i < data.jobsBreakdown.length; i++){

                 str +='Job Title : '+data.jobsBreakdown[i].description+' <br> Total Number of People Engaged in Occupency : '+data.jobsBreakdown[i].value+' <br> Percentage of Occupancies in Area : '+data.jobsBreakdown[i].percentage.toPrecision(2)+'% <br><br>';
               }
              _myContentArea.innerHTML = str;
            }
            });
        }

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes! That works perfectly to my search bar. However, due to there being other HTML i have not shown that is in the <body>, when i search a postcode, it removes anything else in the body with the API data, any idea how I would change this so it doesnt affect any of the data already on the page?

Comment: I updated the answer to include how to not blow away the body content - need to target something other than the body if you don't want it to be replaced with the content.

Comment: Aw Kyle dont worry figured it out! Thanks again, upvotes will be appreciated guys ahaha